# Returning Error If Radio Button NOT selected - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I've searched through a lot of previously asked questions about php and radio buttons but I haven't yet found something helping in my situation. I'm building a quiz for a server-side scripting class. I'm stuck on the actual quiz part. I want an error message to echo if the user does NOT select an answer to a question. Instead when I hit the submit button without selecting any options, I'm automatically redirected to the results page. How do I correct my code so that the user is given the error message if they hit submit without answering all of the questions? Below is the current code i've written out in an attempt to check the radio buttons and next steps.

```
<div id="question5"> <!-- each quiz question gets this set up -->
<h2 id="question5_error">WAIT! You did not pick an answer to this question!</h2>
<p>5. What creature pulls the Hogwarts carriages?<br>
<input type="radio" name="creature" value="Cornish Pixies" <?php if (isset($_SESSION["creature"]) && $_SESSION["creature"]="Cornish Pixies"){ echo"checked";} ?> > Cornish Pixies<br> <!-- php code checks to see if radio button has been selected-->
<input type="radio" name="creature" value="Clydesdales" <?php if (isset($_SESSION["creature"]) && $_SESSION["creature"]="Clydesdales"){ echo"checked";} ?> > Clydesdales<br>
<input type="radio" name="creature" value="Hippogriffs" <?php if (isset($_SESSION["creature"]) && $_SESSION["creature"]="Hippogriffs"){ echo"checked";} ?> > Hippogriffs<br>
<input type="radio" name="creature" value="Thestrals" <?php if (isset($_SESSION["creature"]) && $_SESSION["creature"]="Thestrals"){ echo"checked";} ?> > Thestrals<br>

<input type="hidden" name="sent" value="sent" onclick="Project1_Page2.php">
<input type="submit" name="goresults" value="Get Results?">|<input type="reset" name="resetquiz" value="Reset Quiz.">
</form> 
</article>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["sent"])){
echo "<script type = 'javascript'>";
if(!isset($_GET["question1"])){ // QUIZ QUESTION 1 CHECK
       $_SESSION["author"]=$_GET["author"];
    }
    else{
        echo "document.getElementById('question1').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
        document.getElementById('question1_error').style.display = 'block';";
    }
if(!isset($_GET["question2"])){ // QUIZ QUESTION 2 CHECK
    $_SESSION["godfather"]=$_GET["godfather"];
    }
    else{
        echo"document.getElementById('question2').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
        document.getElementById('question2_error').style.display = 'block';";
    }
if(!isset($_GET["question3"])){ // QUIZ QUESTION 3 CHECK
    $_SESSION["prison"]=$_GET["prison"];
    }
     else
    {
        echo"document.getElementById('question3').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
        document.getElementById('question3_error').style.display = 'block';";
    }   
if(!isset($_GET["question4"])){ // QUIZ QUESTION 4 CHECK
    $_SESSION["badguy"]=$_GET["badguy"];
    }
    else
    {
        echo"document.getElementById('question4').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
        document.getElementById('question4_error').style.display = 'block';";
    }
if(!isset($_GET["question5"])){ // QUIZ QUESTION 5 CHECK
    $_SESSION["creature"]=$_GET["creature"];
    }
    else
    {
        echo"document.getElementById('question5').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
        document.getElementById('question5_error').style.display = 'block';";
    }
echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you researched standard form validation? A check for this could be done client-side (in addition to server-side checks).

Comment: i haven't outside of what we've discussed in class - which has been pretty basic and did not deal with radio buttons. I'll look into it now thought.

Comment: `session_start();` (hidden) in there somewhere? Make use of `empty`

Comment: I have the session_start(); at the very top of the page. 
let me post the radio button code as well....

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using radios you have set their attribute name to one like

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="question" value="1" />
    <input name="question" value="2" />
    <input name="question" value="3" />
    <input name="question" value="4" />
</form>
```

in this way you set your logic statement like so.

```
    if(isset($_POST['question'])){

    //here you put the the right answer based on the user what he/she chose.


    }
```

I suggest you to use POST is secured. If you are using GET the values of radio will appear on the url. I hope this will help.

Peace

Comment: you can also add else if not isset to show the error.

Comment: I did add an if(!isset) for displaying an error. it doesn't populate but now I get an 'undefined index' error for each of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML, it's hard to tell but here are some suggestions

in your form tag, remove "Action" attribute

```
<form method="post/get" >
```

then create a variable

```
$haserror = false;
```

and I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here, but change the code like this

```
if(!isset($_GET["question1"])){ // QUIZ QUESTION 1 CHECK
       $_SESSION["author"]=$_GET["author"];
        echo "document.getElementById('question1').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
        document.getElementById('question1_error').style.display = 'block';";
```

$haserror = true;
        }

do the same for all checkboxes

then at the end do your if to show the result page

```
if(!$haserror)
{
    echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=newpage.php">';

}
```

however I suggest to rewrite the whole thing, because you are approaching it in a wrong way

Comment: as for re-writing.... the current format was taken for a sample we've worked with in class so i'm not sure where i would begin.